# WebRequest to download XML Feed

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

This is my first time working with a webservice and I tried looking up all the resources on the web but I wasn't able to get it to work.

I have to use this [XML](http://rss.timegenie.com/world-time.xml) in my windows phone application and I want the application to retrieve it when the user wants to. I know how to parse the XML but I am just not able to get the XML from the XML feed.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I tried calling the webservice to get the XML feed:

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://rss.timegenie.com/world-time.xml");
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(OnDownloadStringCompleted);
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(uri);

Comment: but I couldn't manage to! The program never goes into the 'OnDownloadStringCompleted' event handler to parse the XML

Comment: If you are formatting the Uri really like above, it cannot download anything. It must be full URL with "http://", otherwise it will end up in finding no target.

Comment: I did it with the "http://", it still didnt work! Infact I always tried with http, somehow it didn't show up here when i posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of tutorials for this type of problem available on the wider web.

For example, try the 3 line solution from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/156610/WP7-WebClient-vs-HttpWebRequest

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, ev) => { responseTextBlock.Text = ev.Result; };
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.sherdog.com/rss/news.xml"));
```